# How to find the source code by a simple method

Tags: source-code

As I know,the *Linux* is a open source project,which mean we can find all code that build this system.

But that is too hard for me.

Is there a simple method which can check the source code of any command? Such as the function `hostname`.  I find it will write the information into its configure file(it may be not `/etc/sysconfig/network` in *CentOS 6.3* I think). 
 I hope to find the real configure file.  So how to find a source code about a command(such as `hostname`) by a simple method?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528267/where-can-i-find-source-code-for-linux-core-commands

Comment: @steve Thanks for your link..That's very useful.

Comment: welcome.  sometimes a google search such as "hostname.c site:github.com" yields useful results for this type of query.

Comment: On the other hand, in this instance it does not yield useful results.

Comment: You must ask the packaging system which package provided the command, and how it was built.  This might need to be done recursively for dependencies.

Comment: I don't think the operative question here ("Is there a simple method which can check the source code of any command?") is too broad. The answer is just "no".

Answer (score 5):

There's no **simple method**.  But it's doable for files which are part of an RPM:

- `rpm -qf` for a given filename identifies the package
- `rpm -qi` for a given package tells a little about where the program came from.
- In particular, if it's a CentOS package, you can find a source-rpm (".srpm") on CentOS's web/ftp-server.  That can be unpacked to get the source-tarball and patches.

If it's not in an RPM, it's hard to find the source unless you know how the file got there.  For non-CentOS packages, the packager **may** identify the source location, maybe **not**.

For instance, your example `hostname` **might** be provided by *coreutils*, but RPM says it is not:

```
$ rpm -qi `rpm -qf /usr/bin/hostname`
Name        : hostname
Version     : 3.13
Release     : 3.el7
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Fri Jul  4 13:23:13 2014
Group       : System Environment/Base
Size        : 19449
License     : GPLv2+
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Thu Jul  3 21:54:35 2014, Key ID 24c6a8a7f4a80eb5
Source RPM  : hostname-3.13-3.el7.src.rpm
Build Date  : Mon Jun  9 17:48:44 2014
Build Host  : worker1.bsys.centos.org
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
Vendor      : CentOS
URL         : http://packages.qa.debian.org/h/hostname.html
Summary     : Utility to set/show the host name or domain name
Description :
This package provides commands which can be used to display the system's
DNS name, and to display or set its hostname or NIS domain name.
```

Since the *Vendor* is **`CentOS`**, you can find the source on CentOS's site.  Or you could follow the given URL (which can take some work).  In this case, Debian offers a link to browse the [source code](https://sources.debian.net/src/hostname/3.18/), because Debian maintains the program.  In cases where they do not, often a tar-ball is the best you'll find.